# Error with subset

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` which I want to subset based on a list of certain IDs. I want to extract all the rows from this `data.frame` which have the same ID as my variable "genes".  So far I have:

```
Final_Genes <- subset(Merged_Results,Merged_Results$Entrez.ID == genes, select = c(1:8))
```

but this produces an error,

```
Warning messages:

    1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
      longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
    2: In `==.default`(Merged_Results$Entrez.ID, genes) :
      longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Which to be honest I don't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
Final_Genes<-Merged_Results[Merged_Results$Entrez.ID==genes,1:8]
```

This assumes that "genes" is that same as a single Entrez.ID. If genes is acutally a vector of several "Entrez.ID"s you could replace the `==` with `%in%`

Comment: Final_Genes<-Merged_Results[Merged_Results$Entrez.ID%in%genes,1:8], worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help. I must learn fully how to correctly subset in R.

Comment: Glad to hear it - for this and your the other questions you have asked - if you get an answer that works you should up-vote and accept them so that folks know that the question has been dealt with.

Comment: Will do, sorry about that! But I cannot up vote until I have a rep of 15.

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute == with %in% and it worked for me, even with the subset command.